# Polygamma function in mathematical physics

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, poly-gamma-function

Are there situations in which the [polygamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) pops up naturally in a mathematical physics context? In particular: are there examples of potentials having some interest for which the dependence on the distance is expressed in terms of $\psi^{(n)}$?

**Update**: While Carlo Beenakker's answer is clearly useful, the references therein still don't contain exactly what I'm looking for in the second part of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Abou-Salem, L. I., *A study on baryons spectroscopy using digamma-function as interacting potential*, https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.6743 studies using the digamma function as an interaction potential (for quarks in baryons).

Answer (score 9):

**Q:** Are there situations in which the polygamma function pops up naturally in a mathematical physics context?

**A:** Certainly, for example:

- [On one dimensional digamma and polygamma series related to the evaluation of Feynman diagrams](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0505051)
- [Decoherence of black hole superpositions by Hawking radiation](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-08426-4?proof=tr) (equation 7)
- [Exact Classical and Quantum Solutions for a Covariant Oscillator Near the Black Hole Horizon](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.03970) (equation 3.20)
- [Mathematical Aspects of Vacuum Energy on Quantum Graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.2707) (equation 88)